# Jenkins pipeline: fail build on string found in build console

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Using jenkins pipeline, I want to fail build when a word (for example, "FATAL") is found in build log.

There is a [Text Finder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/text-finder) plugin that can do it in freestyle jobs, but one cannot use it in pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) which also support Jenkins Pipeline jobs. It's working for us.

### Global Rules

We configured some global rules in `Manage Jenkins->Configure System->Console Output Parsing`. The files configured there are placed at a location accessible to the Jenkins Master, e.g.

```
# /home/jenkins/default.rules (on the jenkins master machine)
error /ERROR/
```

E.g. having a rule set called 'default' which refers to `/home/jenkins/default.rules' you could use the following (the`parsingRulesPath`you can get using the snippet generator selecting`default` rules):

```
echo "ERROR: Some error"
node {
    step([$class: 'LogParserPublisher',
        failBuildOnError: true,
        parsingRulesPath: '/home/jenkins/default.rules',
        useProjectRule: false])
}
```

### Project Rules

Turns out that there's no need to have a global configuration entry. You may also use rules located in your workspace, like:

```
echo "ERROR: Some error"
node {
    // Usually I assume a project rules file will be stored in
    // some repository and are not generated on the fly
    writeFile(file: 'project.rules', text:
'''
error /ERROR/
''')
    step([$class: 'LogParserPublisher',
        failBuildOnError: true,
        projectRulePath: 'project.rules',
        useProjectRule: true])
}
```

Although the examples above are for scripted pipeline it should be easy to apply them to declarative pipeline as well.

Comment: Tried https://pastebin.com/8BvRECpS but couldn't get it working. It throws "Failed to parse console log: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: <valid-existing-accessible-file>"

Comment: Did you fully configure the log Parser plugin? It needs some configuration file at a place accessible to the master.

Comment: Jenkins admins added an entry to "Manage Jenkins/Console Output Parsing/Parsing Rules" that refers to "${WORKSPACE}/failOnFATAL". Only after that the same pipeline https://pastebin.com/8BvRECpS began to work

Comment: Good to know you got it working :) The setup for this plugin is probably not straight-forward. I'll add some details on how we did the setup.

Comment: Think in your example you're mixing the project and global rules setup. If the rules are located in the workspace there should be no need to define a global rule entry. Can you try again setting `useProjectRule: true`?

Comment: It does work with `useProjectRule:true` and `projectRulePath: path` but the latter is [not documented](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) at all.

Comment: Didn't check the documentation though. Usually I try first with the snippet generator - which is working in this case :). Thanks for the hint about the missing documentation, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    echo Blabla
                    echo FATAL error
                '''
            }
        }

        stage('Results') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def logz = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(10000);
                    def result = logz.find { it.contains('FATAL') }
                    if (result) {
                        error ('Failing due to ' + result)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But requires several script approvals from Jenkins admins.

And there is an approval request that states "Approving this signature may introduce a security vulnerability! **You are advised to deny it.**"

Comment: To be honest I would not manually parse the jenkins log as it involves playing outside the sandbox or approving the signature as well as `@NonCPS`. Btw.: It's not safe to use the `rawBuild` directly as it does not implement serializable. You have to put it into a `@NonCPS` method. Otherwise sooner or later you may get an exception.

Comment: Furthermore if the log contains more than 10000 lines it would not find the text.

Comment: @JoergS how did you manage to get this done without using the `rawBuild`? Thanks

Comment: @vhbazan: There's a plugin for that - as explained in my answer. :)